# Oracle SQL Converting Rows Into Column for similar fields

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, transpose

I have a table with two fields

```
EMPLID | STDNT_GROUP
A1       H025
A1       M050
A1       T100
A2       H070
A2       M075
A3       H100
A3       T025
```

Output

```
Emplid |  Hos  | Tut | Mess
A1       H025    T100  M050
A2       H070    NULL  M075
A3       H100    T025  NULL
```

I want to convert the rows into columns.
If an emplid has group starting with H then Hos ,with T then Tut and if M then Mess.
Is this possible using sql

Answer (score 0):

```
Select emplid, max(case when substr(STDNT_GROUP,1) like 'H%' then STDNT_GROUP else ' ' end ) Hostel, 
max(case when substr(STDNT_GROUP,1) like 'T%' then STDNT_GROUP else ' '  end ) Tuition, 
max(case when substr(STDNT_GROUP,1) like 'M%' then STDNT_GROUP  else ' ' end ) Mess 
from table a
group by emplid
```